# Eclipse debugging / step into method skipping AOP wiring

Tags: eclipse, debugging, springsource

I'm debugging a SpringSource application in Eclipse 3.5 that makes heavy use of AOP to wire up the components.

If I want to step into a method of a class wired with AOP, I first have to step through around 20 layers of SpringSource wiring methods before reaching my own source code again.

Is there a way to configure Eclipse to skip the layers to which it has no source and step directly to my method?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try Windows>Preferences>Java>Debug>Step Filtering.
Check "Use Step Filters" and simply add the packages/classes you wouldn't go to in to the list.
See [Eclipse's help](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-usestepfilters.htm) for more details.

Comment: I am using Kepler and stepping into a proxied interface steps into all sorts of other non-AOP classes (e.g. org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils). After ten rounds of adding another class/package I am given up and asking for advice here...

Answer (score 14):

here my filter for make it work:

package: java.lang.*
package: java.util.*
package: net.sf.cglib.*
package: org.springframework.aop.*

Comment: Anyone searching for where to put these information in Intellij, Check this [How to Open Step Filters in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27902985/3143670)