# Stacktrace folding in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I work on a project that has a lot of AOP-style aspects and interceptors.  Calls between our services tend to have a lot of "junk" between them in stack traces, and it makes reading them unnecessarily wordy, especially when debugging.

Is there a way to get the stack trace view in Eclipse to only show the classes that are under a certain domain or currently loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you use AOP to intercept the calls to Throwable.getStackTace() and modify the return value to eliminate certain packages or classes based on some criteria?

Comment: Sure, but I don't mind a little extra output in production logs.  It's more annoying when I'm stepping through code.  Optimally, I'd love it if I could click "step into" and skip over all of the interceptors.

Comment: @CaptainAwesomePants Then what you want is the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575129/eclipse-debugging-step-into-method-skipping-aop-wiring