# Debugger step filters in IntelliJ?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

Does IntelliJ have a feature similar/like "Use Step Filters" in Eclipse for debugging?

I'm new to IntelliJ and would like to avoid jumping into hibernate or jboss proxy classes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define the *Do not step into the classes* list here:

`Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Debugger` -> `Stepping`

Just add things like `org.hibernate.*` to the list.

Comment: For me its still jumping to classes of package pattern which are added to step filters. Why its happening?