# Hide stack frames in IDE Debugger (e.g. Java9 StackWalker)

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin

Java9's new `StackWalker` feature made me realize that it would be great if Eclipse (preferably, or IntelliJ) could be configured to use a custom StackWalker that could modify the normal Call Stack view in the IDE's Debugger.

What I want to do is to hide e.g. specific technical stack entries when debugging JavaEE programs, but also in many third party support libraries. In general I want the option to leave out specific (customizable) stack frames that are not typically of interest, for instance based on (wildcards of) package or class names. Ideally, "step in" would also automatically skip such frames and step until back inside a "not-suppressed" stack frame.

Does anybody know if such a feature is already available in either Eclipse or IntelliJ. It's OK if it doesn't specifically use StackWalker but something conceptually similar. Or do you know if such a feature is planned in either IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An excellent feature which makes me wonder why both IDE's don't already have this in their core functionality.

**Eclipse:**

Someone described how to do that without Java9 in Eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27332733/3931225.
Sadly that currently only works for Eclipse Luna (4.4).

His work is based on the [stackfilter plugin](https://www.intersult.com/wiki/page/Eclipse%20stackfilter%20plugin) from Intersult, which only works up to Eclipse Indigo (3.7).

Eclipse call stack without any filter:
[image: Eclipse no filter]

Eclipse call stack with stackfilter plugin:
[image: Eclipse with filter]

**IntelliJ:**

I did not find any way to filter the call stack in IntelliJ, but it does have a [step filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27902985/3931225)

Comment: I don't think either part of this answer really addresses the question. The question specifically mentions the Debugger, not the output console. Both of those options deal only with the console.

Comment: @E-Riz you are right. I removed the IntelliJ console stuff from my answer, and added a link to a step filter for IntelliJ. Also added screenshots of the Eclipse plugin to better show it is about the call stack, not the output console.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ has a stack filter in the debugger window. It lets you hide entries from libraries that are not your own code. It is the little filter hopper icon in the top right corner of the stack-frame window

[image: img]

Once turned on, I only see frames coming from my code. As far as I can tell, the debugger respects that selection and does not step into methods that lead to an external library as long as there are stack-frames belonging to your code.

Quickly checking the plugin repository did not reveal any promising plugins that provide additional features.